# javascript setTimeout confusion

Tags: javascript, coffeescript

I am new to javascript/coffeescript.

Can someone explain why this coffeescript/javascript zips thru with no delay?
My thoughts for this first case were that it a call to `updateMap(10)`, would "schedule" a call to `updateMaps(9)` 10 seconds later and that would schedule a call to `updateMaps(8)` and so forth.  The two examples seem basically the same.  What am I missing?

```
coffeescript:

    updateMap = (numUpdates) ->
      console.log("updating, numUpdates = #{numUpdates}")
      if numUpdates > 0 
        $.getScript('/map_markers.js')
        setTimeout(updateMap(numUpdates - 1) , 10000)

javascript:

      updateMap = function(numUpdates) {
        console.log("updating, numUpdates = " + numUpdates);
        if (numUpdates > 0) {
          $.getScript('/map_markers.js');
          return setTimeout(updateMap(numUpdates - 1), 10000);
        }
      };
```

but this set works (has the desired delay).

```
coffeescript:

 updateMap = (numUpdates) ->
   count = 0
   updateMapCallback = ->
     count += 1
     console.log("updating")
     $.getScript('/map_markers.js')
     setTimeout updateMapCallback, 10000 unless count < numUpdates


javascript:

updateMap = function(numUpdates) {
    var count, updateMapCallback;
    count = 0;
    return updateMapCallback = function() {
      count += 1;
      console.log("updating");
      $.getScript('/map_markers.js');
      if (!(count < numUpdates)) {
        return setTimeout(updateMapCallback, 10000);
      }
    };
  };
```

Comment: Because `setTimeout` expects a function, but `updateMap` doesn't return a function. `setTimeout` takes a list of arguments as well.

Comment: @elclanrs I see, and the second example does return a function

Comment: actually I guess I am still confused.  the first example does return "setTimeout(updateMap(numUpdates -1), 10000)"

Comment: It returns the result of the function execution which is not a function. The equivalent for your first example is `return setTimeout(function(){updateMap(numUpdates - 1)}, 10000);`. You also dont need the `return` at that point.

Comment: Thanks to all, I got it now.  and I also found that , as elclanrs pointed out, setTimeout does take a a parameter list. So changing the first example to setTimeout(updateMap, 10000, [numUpdates -1]) makes that example work also.

Answer (score 1):

When you write:

```
updateMap = function(numUpdates) {
        ...
                return setTimeout(updateMap(numUpdates - 1), 10000);
      };
```

You are calling *updateMap* and passing the returned value to *setTimeout* to call later. Since the function keeps calling itself, it will sequentially call itself until `numUpdates - 1` is zero (i.e. *numUpdates* times) as fast as it can (or forever if *numUpdates* is less than zero to start with).

In about 10 seconds, *setTimeout* will try to call the returned value (which is a number) and throw an error *numUpdates* times (if it doesn't hit some other limit and stop in the meantime).